# How can I use Godot's "is_in_group" method in a C# script?

Tags: c#, godot

I am new to both Godot and C#, so I will try to be as clear as possible in my question.

I am trying to recreate Pong by following a tutorial that uses GDScript (not otpimal, but it forces me to "translate" stuff from one language to the other). The problem I'm currently facing is that I want to verify if the ball is hitting the racket or the walls by using groups. For this, the **MoveAndCollide()** method is both moving the ball and returning the colliding **KinematicBody2D** object in this "collision" variable.

```
Godot.KinematicCollision2D collision = MoveAndCollide(direction * delta);
    if (collision != null)
    {
        direction = direction.Bounce(collision.Normal);
        if (collision.Collider.IsInGroup("rackets") //the script doesn't recognize the method IsInGroup, so this line does not work
        {
            //change the ball's speed
        }
    }
```

In the tutorial, the author uses the method **is_in_group**, but it seems to not exist in the mono version.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/o60tav/is_in_group_gdscript_vs_isingroup_c/ ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `IsInGroup` is declared on the `Node` class, but `collider` is defined as `Object`. So you need to cast it to `Node` (`PhysicsBody2D` is probably as close to the actual type that you can get).

This happens on a technicality: The physics server only knows that the physics body is represented by an `Object`, and it does not care if it is a `Node` or not (which can be useful if you work with the API at a lower level). Yet, presumably you are not doing anything of the sort, so go ahead and cast it:

```
if (((PhysicsBody2D)collision.Collider).IsInGroup("rackets"))
{
    //change the ball's speed
}
```

With that said, just in case, you could use a safe pattern, since the above code will throw if the type does not match. I'm going to encourage to check only once by introducing a variable:

```
var body = collision.Collider as PhysicsBody2D;
if (body != null && body.IsInGroup("rackets"))
{
    //change the ball's speed
}
```

C# offers more compact syntax for null checks, however… Godot does not null references to `Node`s when they are freed, instead they mark the instance as invalid. *And as far as I can tell, Godot does not overload equality*. You can check for null and invalid instances at once with `IsInstanceValid`:

```
var body = collision.Collider as PhysicsBody2D;
if (Object.IsInstanceValid(body) && body.IsInGroup("rackets"))
{
    //change the ball's speed
}
```

By the way, you could directly check and cast to `KinematicBody2D`, `RigidBody2D` or `StaticBody2D` instead of `PhysicsBody2D` if you know what you expect.